# How to create a model with calculated columns only in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to create a model which holds only calculated values from multiple tables.

This has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900508/how-to-create-read-only-models-in-rails-with-no-backing-table), but the given solution only works for Rails 2. The solution is essentially the same as Ryan Bates did with tableless models. ([Railscast #193](http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model))

Unfortunately this doesn't work for Rails 3, where there's a different approach ([Railscast #219](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model)). (IMHO these models should be called *database-less models*)

My first idea was to create a new class using the ActiveModel approach and I tried to implement the database functionality myself using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` and pure Arel, but this turned out to be very much work, so right now I'm simply misusing another model:

```
CompletlyUnrelatedModel.select(['SUM(...) AS sum1', 'SUM(...) AS sum2', ...])...
```

But this has some drawbacks. The biggest problem for me is that the returned attributes are always `String` objects (because Rails cannot look at the database schema to determine the column type). Also I really don't like having instances of a certain model contain completly unrelated data.

Comment: Why don't you make a simple class without any ActiveModel features but with needed calculations defined as its class methods?

Comment: That was the first approach I mentioned, but that way I'd miss some of the syntactic sugar, especially things from `ActiveRecord::Relation` like the `select` method, or scopes in general.

Comment: I mean: you create a class, say, `Calc` with the class method `never_ordered` which returns the count of the products that weren't ordered at all. Its body just like this: `Product.where(...).count`. Call it this way: `Calc.never_ordered`. And it's sugar-free :)

Comment: OK, syntax-wise that's actually quite elegant. The reason I didn't thought of that was the fact that calculations are quite expensive (large joins) and it is much cheaper to fetch them in *one* query. On the other hand I might need to cache the values in the future and my model will get its own table after all. :)